How to derive this proposition given this distance function?
You have a power set of natural numbers denoted as $P(\mathbb{N})$. Then you have two sets such that $A,B \in P(\mathbb{N})$. A distance function described below is defined on $P(\mathbb{N})$.
$$ p(A,B) =
\begin{cases}
\frac 1{\min(A\bigtriangleup B)}  & \text{when $A\neq B$} \\
\\ 
0 & \text{when $A=B$}
\end{cases}$$
Then, a proposition as below is derived. How could you derive this proposition? I cannot decipher the left part, especially. I guess it is trying to say that k is in the intersection somehow..
$$p(A,B)\leq \frac{1}{n} \Leftrightarrow k<n\,\, \text {then}\, \,(k\in A \Leftrightarrow k\in B)$$
This is a part of the answer to a question listed in this book.

The claim is:  "If the minimum element of the symmetric difference is $≥n$ then no natural number $<n$ can be in the symmetric difference."

$(\Rightarrow)$: if $p(A,B)\leq\frac1n$, there are two possibilities: either $p(A,B)=0$, in which case $A=B$ (therefore $k\in A\Leftrightarrow k\in B$), or $p(A,B)=\frac1m$, where $n\leq m\in\mathbb{N}$. If $k<n\leq m$, then we know $k$ is not an element of $A\triangle B$, since $k$ is smaller than its minimal element. Hence, if $k$ is in $A$, it must be in $B$ (and vice-versa), so that it's not in $(A\smallsetminus B)\cup(B\smallsetminus A)$.
$(\Leftarrow)$: assume that if $k<n$ then $(k\in A\Leftrightarrow k\in B)$. By way of contradiction, let's assume that $p(A,B)>\frac1n$ (which is bigger than zero), this means that $\min\left(A\triangle B\right)=\frac{1}{p(A,B)}<n$, hence (by the hypothesis) $\left(\min\left(A\triangle B\right)\in A\Leftrightarrow\min\left(A\triangle B\right)\in B\right)$. Either $\min\left(A\triangle B\right)\in A$, in which case $\min\left(A\triangle B\right)\in B$ and $\min\left(A\triangle B\right)\not\in A\triangle B$ (which is an absurd), or $\min\left(A\triangle B\right)\not\in A\Rightarrow\min\left(A\triangle B\right)\not\in B$ and, once again, $\min\left(A\triangle B\right)\not\in A\triangle B$ (which is an absurd). Therefore, $p(A,B)\leq\frac1n$.
This concludes the proof of the equivalency.
